# Pixel annomolies with scipy.ndimage.geometric_transform

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am attempting to implement a displacement map on a numpy image. Here is my implementation.

```
def displaceImage(img,displacementMap,distance=10,angle=45):
    """
    NOTE: If displacementMap is smaller than img, then everthing out of bounds
    is not displaced!
    """
    angle=math.radians(angle)
    img=numpyArray(img)
    displacementMap=numpyArray(displacementMap)
    if len(displacementMap.shape)>2:
        # convert displacement map to grayscale
        displacementMap=colorSpaces.grayscale(displacementMap)
    def dissp(point):
        """
        Called for each point in the array.  Returns a same shaped tuple where it should go.
        """
        if point[0]<displacementMap.shape[0] and point[1]<displacementMap.shape[1]:
            delta=displacementMap[point[0],point[1]]*distance
            toX=point[0]+delta*math.sin(angle)
            toY=point[1]-delta*math.cos(angle)
            if len(point)>2: # array is (w,h,rgb)
                point=(toX,toY,point[2])
            else: # array is (w,h) -- aka grayscale
                point=(toX,toY)
        return point
    img=scipy.ndimage.geometric_transform(img,dissp,mode="nearest")
    return img
```

And below I attempt to use a b&w perlin noise to displace to the top left quadrant of the image.  As you can see from the central leaves/sky area, it appears to be doing what one would expect.  The problem is, of course, the stray pixels everywhere. Thoughts?

[image: resultant image]

Comment: Update:  I thought that perhaps this was due to an uninitialized buffer, so I tried:

`bg=np.copy(img)
img=scipy.ndimage.geometric_transform(img,dissp,output=bg,mode="nearest")`

but it did not fix the problem

Comment: Update 2:  I noticed that setting the geometric_transform to order=1 seemed to work, so I thought that perhaps the curve was developing a "ring" and clipping.  Yet np.clip(img,0.0,1.0) doesn't help.